# extracting of specific values in a cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to extract specific values from a specific cell where `Column A` is the input and `Column B` is the output.

```
Column A               Column B
AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,KL      ABCDEFGH
AB,CD,MN,EF,OP,UV      ABCDEF
QR,AB,ST,CD,GH,WX      ABCDGH
```

The formula i am using in `Column B` is:

`=CONCATENATE(MID(A2,(SEARCH("A",A2,1)),2),MID(B2,(SEARCH("CD",B2,1)),2),MID(B2,(SEARCH("EF",B2,1)),2),MID(B2,(SEARCH("GH",B2,1)),2))`

However if i am to drag down the formula until the last row, it will return a `#VALUE!` since some of the values in the `SEARCH` formula did not appear `Column A`.

So what I need is a generic formula that will only extract the values `AB,CD,EF,GH` OR whatever value is available in `Column A` just like in my example.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would condition on whether or not something exists, and print it accordingly:

[image]

Column B's formula uses an approach that matches

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND(<string>,<within_string>)),"",<string>)
```

and concatenates these using `&`. `ISERROR` avoids error outputs, while also helping to place content (an empty string `""` in this case).